# S3 Bucket Policy for anonymous uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've setup an S3 bucket to allow anonymous uploads.  The goal is to allow uploading but not downloading, but the problem I have found is that not only can I not block downloading of these files, but I do not own them and cannot delete copy or manipulate them in any way.  The only way I am able to get rid of them is to delete the bucket.

Here is the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allow-public-put",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::legendstemp/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works, but I no longer have access to these files using either the Amazon Console or programmatically.

The bucket policy also does not apply to these files because the file owner is not the same as the bucket owner.  I cannot take ownership of them either.

How can setup a bucket policy to allow anonymous upload but not download?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while since this was asked, but I came across this while trying to get this to work myself, and wrote about it in some length in:

https://gist.github.com/jareware/d7a817a08e9eae51a7ea

The gist of it (heh!) is that you **can** do anonymous upload and disallow other actions, but you won't be able to carry out the actions using authenticated requests. At least as far as I can tell.

Hope this helps.